# Search text file and append to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large amount of text, with data nested in items, which start with

```
{"sid"
```

and end with

```
}]},
```

I need to search the text for these items, append every item to a row, and every following statement, like

```
"date_start_session":14644,
```

should become a td showing only

```
14644
```

in the appropriate column.

I need help with the code for separating text into rows and columns.
Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/8cLg3d5s/2/

An example of a reply follows

```
{"response":{"sessions":[{"sid":132312321,"wid":123213213,"date_start_session":123123123,"date_end_session":13213123,"session_duration":213123,"num_pages":11,"uid":132312312,"ip":"214.142.71.134","browser":"chrome","referrer":{"source":"http://www.dsfdsfds.com/affiliates.aspx"},"useragent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586","new_visitor":true,"starred":false,"country":"United States","landing_page":"www.dsfdsfds.com","exit_page":"www.dsfdsfds.com","device_type":"desktop","display_name":"","sessionlink":"http://www.fdsfssdf.com/dashboard/watchsession/132131/13123?pn=1&accessResourceKey=8safasdf8ads7fds78","tags":[],"pages":[{"rid":3123213,"opened_at":321313,"pagetitle":"this is the page title","url":"www.dsfdsfds.com"},{"rid":41241233,"opened_at":321313,"pagetitle":"this is the page title 2","url":"www.dsfdsfds.com"}]}
```

Comment: It looks like the format of the file is JSON. In which case you would be much better using `JSON.parse` instead of hacking around the string to find the properties you need. A full example of the input would help a lot here.

Comment: its about 2500 sid's long. ill try to give a full example of a sid, but the api reply starts with {"response":{"sessions"

Comment: updated the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the content to JSON object and loop through that:

```
var temp = JSON.parse($("#container").text());

for(var item in temp.response.sessions){
   var row = $('<tr>');
   $('#theTable tr:first th').each(function(){
       var td = "<td>" + temp.response.sessions[item][$(this).text()] + " </td>";
       row.append(td);
   })

   $(row[0].outerHTML).appendTo("#theTable");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cLg3d5s/6/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the question using this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cLg3d5s/5/

Here is the code in question.  You can see we parse your text using `JSON.parse()`, and the interate over the sessions using `$.each`.  For each session record, we iterate over the columns, extract the value from the record (`rec[key]`), and then add that to a new `<td>` node.

```
var temp = $("#container").text(),
  columnNames = ['sid', 'wid', 'date_start_session', 'date_end_session',
    'session_duration'
  ];

$.each(JSON.parse(temp)['response']['sessions'], function(_row_index, rec) {
  var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($('table tbody'));
  $.each(columnNames, function(_col_index, key) {
    $('<td>').appendTo($tr).text(rec[key]);
  });
});
```

Comment: I chose the other answer, but your answer works well as well! Thanks!